# Several Cassandra instances on the same node (machine)

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to setup several Cassandra instances on the same host/node, maybe with distinct port or any other unique identification.

Your direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Erwin

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take a look at ccm https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm. It's used for setting up multiple cassandra servers on different localhost ips.

CCM configures the `rpc_address` and `seeds` in cassandra.yaml (and also separate data/log/commit_log locations for each node)
CCM also configures diffrent JMX_PORTs for the servers in cassandra-env.sh where host1 gets port 7100, host2 gets 7200 etc.

Comment: Thanks for fast turnaround response. Is it production ready and maintenance by Datastax?